# How to implement functionality of onBackPressed() in service?

Tags: android, service

I am making app like [My Home Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wq.myhomebutton&hl=en). I have implemented functionality of Home Button and it is working correctly. Now I am stuck how to implement functionality for onBackPressed() and menuButton so that it will act as Hardware backButton or menuButton is pressed and for current resume activity onBackPressed() or menuButton Functionality will be invoked?

Here is my Code
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chatheads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button startService, stopService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startService);
        stopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopService);
        startService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));

            }
        });
        stopService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ChatHeadService.java

```
    package com.example.chatheads;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView homeButton;
    private ImageView backButton;
    private ImageView menuButton;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsHome;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsBack;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsMenu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        homeButton = new ImageView(this);
        backButton = new ImageView(this);
        menuButton = new ImageView(this);

        homeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);
        backButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        menuButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);

        paramsHome = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        paramsHome.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        paramsHome.x = 0;
        paramsHome.y = 100;

        paramsBack = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        paramsBack.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        paramsBack.x = 100;
        paramsBack.y = 100;

        paramsMenu = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        paramsMenu.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        paramsMenu.x = 200;
        paramsMenu.y = 100;

        backButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;

            }
        });

        menuButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;

            }
        });

        // this code is for dragging the chat head
        homeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);

                return false;
            }
        });
        windowManager.addView(homeButton, paramsHome);
        windowManager.addView(backButton, paramsBack);
        windowManager.addView(menuButton, paramsMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (homeButton != null)
            windowManager.removeView(homeButton);
        if (backButton != null)
            windowManager.removeView(backButton);
        if (menuButton != null)
            windowManager.removeView(menuButton);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatheads"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.chatheads.ChatHeadService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```